# how to pop up new buttons by pressing a button at the same place

Tags: user-interface, jbutton

I Need to pop up new Buttons at the same place when I clicked On the Button.
Lets Say 3 new Buttons.
When I Clicked On A Certain Button, three New Buttons of the 1/3 of the size of the clicked Button Should Pop Up in the Place where the previous Button Was Located. That Means the previous Button Should Be invisible Now.
I tried Using **JLists** and tried using to add 3 new **JButtons** But failed. Guess the way I coded them is wrong please Help.

[image]

This What my GUI Looks.
When I clicked On the Swimmer Button I need it to disappear and to make visible 3 option Buttons {"Add Male Swimmer", "Add Female Swimmer" ,"Edit Swimmer"}.Please Help..

Comment: Please Teach Me How To Make Some Other Button Visible At The Same Point When A Certain Button Is Clicked..!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I made a while ago when learning javascript and html that sounds close to what you're trying to achieve:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Checkboxes</title>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <style>
    input[type="checkbox"] {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
    .hidden {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .random {
      position: absolute;
    }
    #thumbsup {
      position: fixed;
      top: 40%;
      left: 0%;
    }
    #time {
      position: fixed;
      top: 2%;
      left: 2%;
      border-style: none;
      font-size: 200%;
    }
    #tUps {
      position: fixed;
      top: 2%;
      left: 10%;
      border-style: none;
      font-size: 200%;
    }
    #tDowns {
      position: fixed;
      top: 2%;
      left: 20%;
      border-style: none;
      font-size: 200%;
    }
  </style>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var time = 0;
    var tUps = 1; //how many thumbs up you've gotten
    var tDowns = 0; //how many thumbs down you've gotten   

    function addCheckbox() {
      if (document.buttons.r1.checked) {
        document.getElementById("r2").style.visibility = "visible";
      }
      if (document.buttons.r2.checked) {
        document.getElementById("r3").style.visibility = "visible";
      }
      if (document.buttons.r3.checked) {
        document.getElementById("r4").style.visibility = "visible";
      }

      return true;
    }

    function addThumbsup() {
      if (document.buttons.r4.checked) {
        document.getElementById("thumbsup").style.visibility = "visible";
        addPoint();
      }
    }

    function init() {
      rd = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
      for (c = 0; c < rd.length; c++) {
        if (rd[c].className == 'random') {
          console.log(rd[c]);
          xCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 95);
          yCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 95);


          rd[c].style.left = xCoord + '%';
          rd[c].style.top = yCoord + '%';
        }
      }
    }

    function thumbsDown() {
      if (document.buttons.r4.checked) { //if you beat the timer, keep the thumb pointing up
        return false;
      } else {
        thumbsup.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(180deg)";
        thumbsup.style.top = "40%";
        thumbsup.style.left = "86%";
        return true;
      }
    }

    function startClock() {
      stopTime = window.setInterval(timer, 100);
    }

    function timer() {
      time += .1;
      document.display.time.value = Number(time).toFixed(1);
      if (time >= 3) {
        thumbsDown();
      }
    }

    function refreshTime() { //separate function for the time that elapses before refreshing 
      window.clearInterval(stopTime);
      window.setTimeout(refresh, 750);
    }

    function refresh() {
      location.reload();
    }

    function addPoint() {
      if (thumbsDown) {
        tDowns++;
      } else {
        tUps++;
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener ?
      window.addEventListener('load', init, false) :
      window.attachEvent('onload', init);
  </script>


  <form name="buttons">

    <div class="random">
      <input type="checkbox" id="r1" onClick="addCheckbox(); startClock();">
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <div class="random">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r2" onClick="addCheckbox();">
      </div>
      <div class="random">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r3" onClick="addCheckbox();">
      </div>
      <div class="random">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r4" onClick="addThumbsup(); refreshTime();">
      </div>
    </div>


  </form>
  <form name="display">
    <input type="text" id="time">
    <input type="text" id="tUps">
    <input type="text" id="tDowns">
  </form>

  <img src="thumbsup.jpg" class="hidden" id="thumbsup">
</body>


</html>
```

Basically you need a function that checks if the required button is pressed and sets the next buttons visibility to true (this is called addCheckbox in my code).
I'm willing to help more, but you need to provide some code to work with.

Comment: thanks For the Answer But I'm Loking for Java Answers.

Comment: How Could I send you My Code!!

Comment: If you Could Please Teach Me How Make Another Button Visible At The Same Place When A certain Button Is Clicked.